# Navigation bar back button with text only

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to set view controller back button to text only.
I tried

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

but it also adding the arrow image that I don't want.
how can I set only text?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add custom UIBarButtonItem embedded with the UIButton :

```
UIButton* someButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[someButton setFrame:frame];
[someButton setTitle: //......
[someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem* someBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:someBarButtonItem];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting leftBarButtonItem on the displayed view controller (not the one that is below and whose backBarButtonItem the app would otherwise display) and handle its taps by calling popViewController: on the navigation controller (assuming that you are using it. If it's just a UINavigationBar without navigation controller, pop the navigation item from that UINavigationBar.

Answer (score 0):

use like this but add this into parent view controller not in the child

```
 self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Details" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

This code hides the back text and arrow ,

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:NO];
[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:nil];
```